# I need to bulk count words for multiple .doc files in any way possible

Tags: windows, macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have both Mac and  Windows machines, and I don't mind having to convert my `.doc` files to `.txt` or whatever format. I just need to bulk count their words automatically.

I used to use a program called "word counter" for Mac, but the latest version fails to recognize the OS X 10.11 as higher than 10.4 and having an older mac just for that purpose doesn't seem worth it.

Edit: The final answer to my problem was these 2 lines. make sure you have the osx terminal open in the folder with all the files in it and type

```
textutil -convert txt *.docx
```

(converts all docx to txt)

then

```
cat *.txt | wc -w
```

(word counts all txt files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will show you the word count for the file.

```
cat <file_path> | wc -w
```

Alternatively for displaying the number of newlines, you can use

```
cat <file_path> | wc -l
```

For multiple files with a continuous naming format like ***file1, file2, file3***; The following command would list the total word count of all the files combined using the wildcard

```
cat <file_path>/file* | wc -w
```

Here * denotes **any**

**EDIT**

As @tripleee mentioned if you are using this in a script or you want the most optimized version, you could leave off `cat` and go straight with

```
wc -w <file_path>/file*
```

Comment: Actually `cat <file_path> | wc -l` displays the number of newlines which to the eye look like paragraphs more than lines.

Comment: @GipsysCosmonaut that's great now I just need something to bulk convert doc to txt because it doesn't work with docx files.

Comment: `wc -w file1 file2 ...` is actually more informative than a redirect when you pass it multiple files (it breaks down the sum per file as well as providing a total), and avoids the [useless `cat`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)

Answer (score 2):

Made some update to @Christian5642's answer for Windows 10.

1. In File explorer, right click column header.

[image]

2. Select More.

[image]

3. Select Word Count.

[image]